# iOS Private Relay - Get its status programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I wanted to know if there is any way or workaround to get any information about if the Private Relay is enabled or not programmatically(In app or own customized network), I have googled a lot for this but unfortunately did not found a major lead on this.

So is there any way to get the status of Private relay And can we open the Private Relay's Setting from our iOS app, I know we can open Settings page specifically to our app but still.. can we implement this?